# Are android kernel versions are same for identical device models?

Tags: kernel

I have a question: if I have two Samsung A52 devices are these both got the same kernel versions?

Comment: Do they have the same OS versions?

Comment: You can check in Settings -> About. Or use command `uname -rv` on `adb shell` or any terminal emulator app.

Comment: @gronostaj yes in case they both have the same android version?

Answer (score 1):

If they are running the same OS version, then they are also running the same kernel version.

Note that by "OS version" I don't exactly mean the same Android version. Phone manufacturers can - and should - release newer OS versions with newer security patches and bugfixes. The Android version doesn't necessarily change with each such update, but OS build version does. Kernel version can change too.

If you're interested in running custom ROMs, then it's also possible that two ROMs based on the same Android version would be running different kernel versions.

Finally, with an unlocked bootloader it's possible to flash a custom kernel to any ROM, custom or not.

Comment: thanks for the information let me make this clear,
Suppose I buy two new Samsung A52s from the factory they both contain the same Kernel versions right?

Comment: @Sultan It's guaranteed only if they come with the same firmware version. But they don't necessarily do. Why are you asking?